# Google APIs: People versus PeopleService

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-contacts-api

While setting up a .NET C# project in Visual Studio, the NuGet Package Manager shows:

Google.Apis.People.v1

Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1

as options to include in the project.  Both are described as client libraries.

Being new to Google APIs, I am unsure which to include in my project.  The project is a standalone Windows Forms Application that will translate an export file from one system into Google Contacts and Contact Groups (Labels).

Which should I include in this type of project?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant download pages for the Nuget Packages:

- `PeopleService` - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1
- `People` - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.People.v1/

From the looks of things, they both serve the same purpose. However, `PeopleService` looks to be the up-to-date version. `People` was last updated 11 Apr 2017 and is on v1.25.0.830, whereas `PeopleService` is still being maintained. My guess is that it was renamed to `PeopleService`, but they kept `People` around for legacy support. The Google API info page also [recommends](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/people/v1) `PeopleService` instead of `People`, so I think it's safe to say you should use `PeopleService` if you're making a new project.